# bash-script error

Tags: bash

bash-5.0-6
trying to run the following script results in syntax-error:

```
wget -nv -O index.html "https://de.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3APrefixindex&namespace=0&from=$buch"
```

the resulting error-message:

```
2020-08-24 20:38:51 URL:https://de.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:Pr%C3%A4fixindex&namespace=0&from=Mathematik%3A_Lineare_Algebra [96400] -> "index.html" [1]
get_wikibooks.sh: 18: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

it seems, that the sign "%" causes the error. But how can I write the script, so that it is useable ?

thanks in advance
bye hans

P.S. My complete code is:

```
set -x
#!/bin/bash
buch=$(zenity --entry --title "Download eines Wikibooks" --text "Bitte geben Sie den Buchtitel an:")
buch=$(echo $buch | sed "s/ /_/g")
mkdir -p ~/wikibooks/$buch
cd ~/wikibooks/$buch
wget -nv -O index.html 'https://de.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3APrefixindex&namespace=0&from=$buch'
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        zenity --error --title "Download eines Wikibooks - Fehler" \
          --text "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten\! \nÜberprüfen sie die Internet-Verbindung und den Buchtitel."
fi
wget -nv -c $(cat index.html | tr '"' '\n’ | egrep "^/wiki$buch" | sort -u | sed "s#^#https://de.wikibooks.org#")
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        zenity --error --title "Download eines Wikibooks - Fehler" \
          --text "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten\! \nÜberprüfen sie die Internet-Verbindung und den Buchtitel."
fi
for i in $(ls); do sed "s#href=\"/wiki/$buch#href=\"./$buch#g" $i > $i.temp; mv $i.temp $i; done
zenity --info --title "Download eines Wikibooks" --text "Herunterladen des Buches erfolgreich\!"
```

Comment: I just tried running `wget -nv -O index.html "https://de.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3APrefixindex&namespace=0&from=$buch"` on my machine with GNU bash, version `4.4.20(1)-release` and it worked fine.  The unterminated quotation must be elsewhere in your `get_wikibooks.sh` file.

Comment: What is the exact content of line 18 of `get_wikibooks.sh`?

Comment: I'm using bash 4.4.20 and that line downloads an ```index.html``` file without an error message. My ```$buch``` variable is obviously empty. Could the value of that variable be where the problem is in your case?

Comment: With our without the `$buch` in your line, there should not be such an error. Try adding `set -x` to get a debug output of what is executed. And please add the script you execute around line 18

Comment: The error message says you have an "Unterminated quoted string".  That is __not__ caused by a `%` sign.  You need to show us line 18 which, it would seem, is _after_ the `wget` command.

Answer (score 1):

The code has quoting errors.  Consider this line:

```
wget -nv -c $(cat index.html | tr '"' '\n’ | egrep "^/wiki$buch" | sort -u | sed "s#^#https://de.wikibooks.org#")
```

The tr command is `tr '"' '\n’`.  The final quote in that command is a unicode (not ASCII) backquote.  This is not valid as a shell-single-quote.

Replace `tr '"' '\n’` with `tr '"' '\n'`.

After you have done that, cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct any remaining errors (important) or warnings (might be important) that it identifies.

Answer (score 0):

Issuing the same command on it's own works fine.
However since you have `$` within the URL, it might be counted a as variable since you re using `"`
try:

```
wget -nv -O index.html 'https://de.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3APrefixindex&namespace=0&from=$buch'
```

note the `'` single quotes.. unless `$buch` is a variable within your bash script.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$buch` IS a variable, but if it is NOT a variable, then you can put `set -u` at the top of the bash script and you will get an error if a variable is referenced before being set.  (That way you'll know if bash is trying to resolve `$buch` as a variable when it shouldn't be.)